# Grid View vs List View for products

Tags: layout, listview, page-layout

I am looking for some general insight on a comparison between grid view and list view in e-commerce and not only.

I want to start from this general research, find the proper terms I don't know at the moment and then get into more specific information.

I am looking for articles, case studies, ux testing, even books, everything you know on the topic. (Layout: Grid View vs List View)

**Screenshot attached.** Please help!

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

> Choose the layout that suits the type of content you’re displaying. A
>   list style layout is for the seated because users' actions tend to be
>   very singular in purpose. They've come to your site to do one thing:
>   browse or read. Present them with content in a standard way and let
>   them just get lost in it.
>
> On the other hand, grid view is for the standing. It's for the
>   restless and curious. Your attention goes from one topic or image to
>   the next and you never want to linger in one spot for too long. And
>   when you get tired of standing, you just click into your topic of
>   interest for more details and have a seat so you can take your time
>   and become completely enthralled.

I've google-found some useful opinions about list vs grid

[List vs Grid View – How do you choose?](http://www.digitalsurgeons.com/thoughts/creative/list-vs-grid-view-how-do-you-choose/)

[List Beats Grid: Linear Feeds Perform Two to Three Times Better Than Grids](http://blog.getprismatic.com/list-beats-grid-linear-feeds-perform-two-to-three-times-better-than-grids-2/)

[Displaying Search Results: Grid View or List View?](http://www.getelastic.com/grid-vs-list/)

Comment: Here's another link to [List Beats Grid](https://declara.com/content/l1xAbzgP)

Answer (score 3):

I've been researching for many weeks about this topic and my conclusion is: ***IT DEPENDS***.

When the users make their first search (or homepage with products) they may want to see a large picture with few details to visually compare one from another. This applies to similar products (like shoes, jackets, furniture, etc). But if your e-commerce application is focused on products very different one from the other (TVs, cars, computers, etc) it is best to show smaller images and more information.

In conclusion, **Grid view** for similar products (where you make your decision by the appearance of the product). **List view** for products with different (and important) information and/or specifications.

Comment: Any articles or books pop to you mind ?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is more important in your data.
For image based content the best option is the grid view. 
For data based content a better option is the list view.