# Grid view vs List view

Tags: lists, grid

A similar question has already been asked here - [Grid View vs List View for products](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60412/grid-view-vs-list-view-for-products) . But i would like to get clarity on some specific facts.

The questions is wether to use 
[image]

or this.
[image]

**Here are a few points to be considered/found from researching**

**Attention from the user**
infinite scroll won't be present and the number of items will be limited. The distribution of attention to each list item must be maximised. In case i'm using the list view the last last items won't get much attention.

**Space for description**
To maximise the attention i can use grid view , but in case of grid view the amount of description i can give is very less compared to the list view.

The basic dilemma is which is to be given more importance ( description or attention) when you are advertising/marketing the items in the list. The items in list will have no relation to each other , so user can only understand about it through description. But attention to all the items must be close to equal since all are of same importance.

Comment: Are you considering the ListView or GridView for a Website or an App?

Comment: It is for a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But attention to all the items must be close to equal since all are of same importance.

Are you sure about this? People know when and how to scroll when there's more on the page than visible. But you might as well be right, than you have given the answer on your own question. The grid view looks the better option then. But think of this:

**If all items draw the same amount of attention, none of them will stand out.**

The real question is: What will draw the users attention to a particular item?

If you want a user with a particular interest to be attracted to a particular item, design that item specifically for that person.

I’m affraid you have to do better than just a description. You can start with a more engaging image and title. Once the attention is drawn to that item you can show a more detailed description with a click, hover or just clever design. There are lots of ways to accomplish this. But you will only know what works best by testing. Try your ideas with people around you to get a quick impression, and later on with potential users. And if you are going to test anyway, try also the list view so you are really sure.

Comment: My requirement may go like this. Say a user can search for apples and find variety of apples. All apples give me the same amount of money to be sold.  So logically thinking all kind of apples should get the same attention. The question is whether to show more apples at a time or more details about each apple.

Comment: But there is something why that particular apple should stand out for that user right? And you think it’s in the description? I would say let it be in the title and subtitle, which is easier to scan than the description. So if someone wants to find the right apple for a pie. Make the title like "Sweet and crumbly", and the subtitle "Best processed in food". This is just an example of course but I hope you get the point.